# Does updating the partition column of a record affect the ETL process? How will it be handled?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Assume, we have student data stored in a table. That table is partitioned by student's class.
As of initial load Student ID 1001 is in 7th Standard, And his/her data is stored under the partition 'class=07' folder in S3.
In the next load, we get it that student ID 1001 is actually in 9th Standard, and we update the record to show this data.

Since the partition is done based on the class, how will this affect the data/ETL process. etc.

Haven't tried anything yet, just a thought experiment. I might need to implement this on a large scale

Answer (score 0):

It will trigger a shuffle operation which is expensive